# android media player is not playing audio file from url which has space or special character

Tags: android

i am trying to make media player for audio file.

when i play a file which has space or special character like this

```
[str=**http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/Songs/Baek Chan & Joo Hee of 8eight.mp3**;]
```

using

```
    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(str);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

media player does not play file.

if i use this type of `url:- str=**http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/Songs/Baek.mp3**;`

it works properly. please tell me what should i do to solve this type of problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use the `URLEncoder.encode` method see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
so every special character are converted into their hexadecimal value prepended by '%'. For example: '#' -> %23.

like this

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URLEncoder.encode(str,"UTF-8"));
```